# Using DirectShow c++'s API with C# (COM component)

Tags: c#, c++, com, directshow, regsvr32

I am developing a Windwos form application using Directshow.
At start I was using Quarts.dll located in windows/system32 in purpose of getting the basic API of Directshow. 
After a while I realized I need the whole API of Directshow, because I need to create a new Video Renderer filter (VM7).
For this to take place I need to have access to some of the interfaces provided in Directshow c++ API.
I discovered that Directshow is a COM component and I can get access to his API in C#, if I find the right way to bound with it.

Now, this is what I did to get access to the API:

I found out that the C++ API is provided in the Windows SDK. The API I need are located in devenum.idl, axcore.idl and axextend.idl.

Those are interface description language files, and I found out that I can use the midl.exe through the cmd to create a .tlb file (a typelib), now with the file's help I can get access to the interfaces I need. But to use the midl compiler I needed to create a new .idl file that contains the interfaces I want, it looks like that:

```
import "devenum.idl";
import "axcore.idl";
import "axextend.idl";

[
uuid(A68F9934-FDB9-4AAE-A631-F9307171B2FA),
helpstring("DirectShow interfaces")
]
library DirectShow
{
    interface IFilterGraph;
    interface ICreateDevEnum;
    interface IGraphBuilder;
    interface ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
    interface IFileSinkFilter;
    interface IFileSinkFilter2;
    interface IAMAudioInputMixer;
};
```

That required to create a new guid.

After that I was able to run the midl and create a .tlb file, But when I tried to add reference to the .tlb file it gave an error.

I found a way to create a .dll file from this .tlb file, by running tlbimp.exe through the cmd on the .tlb file. It created a .dll that I succeeded to add to my project.
Now Visual Studio knows how to interact withh all the interfaces I was trying to get.

But for the problem I am facing now:

At runtime I am getting this error:

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {56A868A9-0AD4-11CE-B03A-0020AF0BA770} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).**

I can see that the component clsid of the problem is not the clsid of the library in the .idl file I created, it could testify that the problem is on the import files I am using, maybe a bad guid in those files?

I also think the problem can be that the .dll is not registered on my system. I tried to use the regsvr32 but It gave me an error saying:

**The module "directshow.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found...**

Now somebody please save me and tell me how to fix the problem or suggest me a different solution of using the C++ API of Directshow through c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have hard time interfacing DirectShow API from C# code directly. Luckily, this work is already done and available as [DirectShow.NET Library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/). It comes with all bindings you need and sample projects as well.

Specifically this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {56A868A9-0AD4-11CE-B03A-0020AF0BA770} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

tells that you are trying to use `IGraphBuilder` interface identifier `IID` as a coclass identifier `CLSID`. This expectedly does not work out.

Comment: I have seen this article at code-project, the guy rewrote all the interfaces to c# what do you think I should use? [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2615/DirectShow-NET)

Comment: CodeProject article might be not up to date. The library behind my link is, is widely used and is perhaps the best way out for you for "DirectShow in C#" task.

Comment: So you are saying that there isn't a way of getting the interfaces from c++?

Comment: DirectShow is native API and you can have it in full in C++ without type libraries. This was not your real question, was it? Your first error quoted in bold is IID/CLSID confusion, the next one is that you don't really build a valid COM DLL. To not reinvent this wheel because these are unlikely that only issues you are going to have, I suggested to leverage this open source lib...

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I will use the open source lib, it looks great.